# Valid visa in an expired US passport and an additional renewed passport

Tags: visas, india, us-citizens, bom

I have a valid Indian visa in the US for an expired passport. Additional I have a new US passport. Can I carry both my passports with me when I'm traveling to India? Will I have problems at the immigration at Bombay airport?

Comment: see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/if-my-old-passport-has-a-valid-indian-visa-and-i-forget-it-how-else-can-i-get-i?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  And let's turn the volume down on the post.

Comment: @Anjie: I removed all the caps. Please check if it still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the visa in your expired passport hasn't been cancelled, then you need to travel with both of your passports. The passport with the valid visa and a valid passport. However, [this website](https://indiavisa.travisaoutsourcing.com/faqs#transfer) strongly advises you to transfer the visa to a new passport.